# using android to power a PIC board

Tags: batteries, android

I have a PIC board that I want to power from my mobile phone when the phone is on and keep the phone topped up from a solar panel.

I think I want to:

1. access battery terminals in phone directly (with the phone back off) - I can see the battery terminals have 4 v
2. have a switch in the power lead between the battery terminals and PIC board controlled by the phone (working on this)
3. top up phone battery from solar panel - I'm not sure about this - can I just wire up a 5V solar panel?

What do the battery terminals want to 'see' voltage wise to charge?  do I have to prevent overcharging?

Comment: Directly charging the phone battery while installed is an incredibly bad idea.

Comment: You are better off with an external solar cell charger

Comment: So, I can charge up phone normally through an external charger/usb connection.  But I don't have access to the phone battery voltage through this connector (to tap off 5V power from the phone battery).  So could I charge up phone normally, and tap off power directly from the battery terminals in the back of the phone? dont see why not?

Comment: Yes, that is better, use a diode, and keep in mind that draining the battery to low will kill it too.

Answer (score 1):

To answer your question. Your battery want to see a "constant current"
This is a very good example of how charging current should evolves with battery voltage. It depends on your battery ratings...
[image: Current Vs Voltage on Li-ion battery. Source Linear Technology]

Some reading about Lithium battery charging can be found [here](http://www.digikey.com/en/articles/techzone/2012/sep/a-designers-guide-to-lithium-battery-charging).

Search for **battery charger IC** from diferent manufacturers (for Linear [here](http://www.linear.com/products/battery_charger_ic)).

The good news are that your mobile phone already incorporates a Battery charger IC, so apply 5V to the USB charging connector and you will be charging your battery.

Comment: This doesn't at all address what seems to me to be the main part of the question which is "I have a PIC board that I want to power from my mobile phone".

Comment: but useful information anyway, thanks!

Comment: @brhans well, for me it address this question "What do the battery terminals want to 'see' voltage wise to charge? do I have to prevent overcharging?"